# Transfering form data in the url with post and get

Tags: php, url, url-routing

I have a problem. I need to transfer a message that a user types to the same page (cause I need to save it to the database). I have a form and a 'submit button'.

If I use the command 'post' I am able to save transfer the data to the same page and save it after extracting the post variables.

Problem is that I dont send the page_id in the url (I could acheive it with GET method, but I cant use it, cause the users message could be too long to go into the url).

I tried to do some javascript code, to transfer the 'submit' button to simple button and do a redirect..:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('messageSent').addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location = 'article.php?articleID=<?php echo $_REQUEST['pageID']; ?>';
}, false);
</script>
```

But then the POST variables are lost.

Basically, what I want is to achieve the effect of post and get, I want to post the the variables while encoding the url to look like this:

```
home.php?pageID=<?php echo $_REQUEST['pageID']; ?>
```

The page should repost to itself as post request with the pageID set..

How do I achieve that?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an URL containing the page id in action of form. For example:

```
<form action="home.php?pageID=<?php echo $_REQUEST['pageID']; ?>" method="post">
</form>
```

Comment: awesome and easy solution..Thank you..I have never thought about it.

Comment: This will not POST the page ID value. It will be transferred as a GET variable. Only what you place inside the form will be POSTed

Comment: I know, part of the variables that I want to be posted will be posted. and the action will set the URL..so that I will be able to write $_Post['form variable'] and $_Get['url variable']; /// that what I was looking for

Comment: @Matrix ah, then I misunderstood your question. Removed downvote.

Comment: Please note that this code is vulnerable to cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to dynamically build a form, populate it with the POST values, and submit it using JavaScript:

```
<form id="myform" action="target.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['pageID']; ?>">
</form>

<script>
 // ... eventually.... 
 document.getElementById("myform").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: That wasnt exactly what I meant..I thought at the beginning to use a hidden variable too..but that wasnt my aim